# Can I generate token using DRF after I validate the user using LDAP?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In the beginning I will ask everyone to excuse me if my question is wrong/not properly framed because I am new starting something new which I am totally not aware of, I need to learn this as it is very much needed for my work. Question goes as below,

I am planning to develop a framework using Django, to authenticate users to use my framework I need to validate user using my org LDAP. In my framework I have multiple API endpoints (as I am developing API end points using Django), for each end point I need user to have permission/authentication. Here is the catch, when I am trying to authenticate user using LDAP I am not able to generate tokens (access or refresh). If I generate token I am not able to authenticate user using LDAP. I tried integrating both part but I am getting error ( may be I dont know how to integrate as I am new to Django). I need help from you guys like....I need to validate user using LDAP and after validation I need to generate token (access and refresh). Please help me with this... Below is my code snippet.

Code of LDAP validation:

`views.py`

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
from test_report.settings import AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH
from .auth import MyLdapBackend
from . import ldap_auth
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def userLogin(request):
    response = {'success': False}
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            requestData = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
            username = requestData["name"]
            password = requestData["password"]
            if not username:
                response = {'success': False, 'note': 'Please provide valid username'}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), 'application/json')
            elif username == " ":
                response = {'success': False, 'note': 'Please provide valid username'}
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), 'application/json')
            auth = MyLdapBackend()
            user = auth.authenticate_ldap_user(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user, backend='userauth.auth.MyLdapBackend')
            #ldap_auth.custom_sync_user_relations(user, AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH)
            response = {'success': True, 'note': "logged in"}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, " error ")
            response = {'success': False, 'note': "not logged in"}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), 'application/json')
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path('auth', views.userLogin)]
```

`auth.py`

```
import ldap
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from test_report.settings import AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI
from test_report import settings
#from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

class MyLdapBackend(object):
    def authenticate_ldap_user(self, username = None, password = None):
        connection = ldap.initialize(AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI)
        ldap_username = "CN=" + username + ",OU=Users,OU=xxxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=com"
        ldap_password = password
        #  # check user credentials
        try:
        #        LDAPBackend.authenticate(self, username, password)
            connection.simple_bind_s(ldap_username, ldap_password)
        except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
            return None
         # authentication against the ldap succeed from here
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username = username )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User( username = username, password = ldap_password )
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
        return user # that's what your backend has to return on success
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None`
```

Below code from DRF....

`views.py`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username
        # ...
        return token
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = ['/api/token','/api/token/refresh']
    return Response(routes)`
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenRefreshView)

urlpatterns = [path('', views.getRoutes),path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```